# Data.table: update column value by summing the column value left of it

Tags: r, data.table

I need to update the year columns of a data.table so that they indicate the sum of the values up to and including that year.  I have a data.table that looks similar to this:

| id | year_2019 | year_2020 | year_2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 9 | 2 | 4 |

I tried the following code, but it assigned the total sum over the row to each year, so 7 for the first row, 7 for the second, and 15 for the third.

```
dt[,(paste0("cumulative_", year_columns)) := rowSums(.SD, na.rm=TRUE), .SDcols = year_columns)
```

The desired end result looks like this:

| id | cumulative_2019 | cumulative_2020 | cumulative_2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 9 | 11 | 15 |

Answer (score 2):

There's superfast `rowCumsums` in the matrixStats package, you can pipe it in `data.table`.

```
> matrixStats::rowCumsums(as.matrix(dt)) |> data.table::data.table()
   year_2019 year_2020 year_2021
1:         5         6         9
2:         0         1         5
3:         2         7         9
```

---

*Data:*

```
dt <- structure(list(year_2019 = c(5, 0, 2), year_2020 = c(1, 1, 5), 
    year_2021 = c(3, 4, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x559c62158ac0>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum`.

```
dt <- data.table(
  "year_2019" = c(5, 0, 2),
  "year_2020" = c(1, 1, 5),
  "year_2021" = c(3, 4, 2)
)

dt
   year_2019 year_2020 year_2021
1:         5         1         3
2:         0         1         4
3:         2         5         2
```

However, cumsum applys to columns in default, like:

```
cumsum(dt)
   year_2019 year_2020 year_2021
1:         5         1         3
2:         5         2         7
3:         7         7         9
```

So you have to apply it to rows.

```
t(apply(dt, 1, cumsum))
     year_2019 year_2020 year_2021
[1,]         5         6         9
[2,]         0         1         5
[3,]         2         7         9
```